# Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312") get Exception: 'GB2312' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, character-encoding, .net-framework-version

In ms doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding, in **Listing of encodings** section, in the encodings table, at the **gb2312** row, there is a mark in **.NET Framework support** column, that means gb2312 is natively supported by .NET Framework.

But when I call

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312")
```

in my program, it gives me a Exception in a Win11 machine and another Windows Server 2008 machine, with message:

```
'GB2312' is not a supported encoding name
```

But it gets that gb2312 Encoding correctly in my Win10 machine in which I build the program.

My program is built with .NET Framework 4.6.2, so I think gb2312 is natively supported, so what is wrong?

I did some search, which suggest

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(new CodePagesEncodingProvider())
```

but it's a solution for .NET Core. I think it doesn't address the root cause and isn't a good fix for .NET Framework.

UPDATE: the code which call *GetEncoding* is inside a dll

Comment: Did you compare the installed _runtime_ versions on those machines?

Comment: Does it work if you use the code page number (936) instead of the name?

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, no significant difference related to the issue between machines.

Comment: Thanks @dan04, code page number(936) of gb2312 doesn't work either

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312");
```

Comment: Just add this once in your application, not on every call. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular issue, I would share my journey in case someone run into the same situation.

Before the root cause, I must apologize that I didn't describe all details clearly in my question, the calling to *System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312")*
is inside a dll I made, which is built on .NET Framework.

Then some guy made an exe which call an api in my dll and route to the  *GetEncoding* line. The root cause is his exe is built on .NET Core, the effective runtime is derived from his exe, that's .NET Core, not from my dll.

So the real problem is still .NET Core doesn't support **gb2312** by default, just as the doc says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.

The solution is to also build the exe on .NET Framework. Or take @Vic F's answer if one have to base his on .NET Core.